# mysql muliple queries in one statement

Tags: php, mysql

I've looked around on stackoverflow for a similar question, but haven't found exactly what I was looking for, so here goes. In phpMyAdmin you can have multiple queries in one statement and it executes it for you, eg:'

```
UPDATE `test` WHERE `test2` = 4;
UPDATE `test` WHERE `test4` = 8;
UPDATE `test` WHERE `test8` = 1;
```

Now if I try to do something like that in PHP, it doesn't work at all. eg:

```
 $test = 'UPDATE `test` SET `value` = "123" WHERE `test2` = 4;
             UPDATE `test` SET `value` = "321" WHERE `test4` = 8;
             UPDATE `test` SET `value` = "533" WHERE `test8` = 1;';
    mysql_query($test);
```

Gives and error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near ';  UPDATE
>   `test` SET value = "123" WHERE `test2`
>   = 4;  UPDATE `test` SE' at line 1

Is it even possible to combine, say, multiple queries like above, in one statement? I want to do this in the following situation: (The logic behind this is probably very bad, but I don't have much MySQL experience, so please let me know if there's a better way to do it)

The following loops over a couple of times:

```
function SaveConfig($name, $value)
{
        global $sql_save_query;
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `config` WHERE `name` = "'.$name.'"';
    $res = mysql_query($sql);

    if($res)
    {
        $sql_save_query .= 'UPDATE `config` SET value = "'.$value.'" WHERE `name` = "' .$name. '"; '."\n";
    }
    else
    {
            $sql_save_query .= 'INSERT INTO `config`(`id`,`name`,`value`) VALUES("","' .$name. '","' .$value. '"); '."\n";
    }
}
```

Then after the loop finishes it runs:

```
mysql_query($sql_save_query);
```

Which gives an error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near ';  UPDATE
>   `config` SET value = "" WHERE `name` =
>   "fcolour2";  UPDATE `config` SE' at
>   line 1

Now my other option (in my mind) is to just execute an SQL query after each loop, one query at a time. But wouldn't that be bad/slow/bad practice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the php API forbids you to issue multiple queries in a single call to reduce the chance of an [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attack to your code (think of what would happen if I passed `'; UPDATE users SET admin=1 WHERE username='hacker'` to your login script as username). You need to either execute multiple statements, or wrap the logic of your statements into a single statement (which is not possible in your case).

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to execute multiple queries using `mysql_query`.

You can perform multiple inserts at once using this syntax:

```
INSERT INTO table (col1, col2) VALUES (0, 1), (2, 3), (4, 5); -- Insert 3 rows
```

In general less queries = better but for updates you just have to do them.

Answer (score 1):

The loop you have in your example is indicative of an architectural problem.

If you are dealing with an existing record, pass the primary key - then you don't need the select at all - you can just run an update statement.

If you are dealing with a new record, pass no key - then you know to run an insert statement.

Answer (score 1):

probably you can use [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;
```

Some other useful links

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/01/18/insert-on-duplicate-key-update-and-replace-into/

Answer (score 0):

```
$sqls = explode(";",$test);
foreach ($sqls as $key=>$sql) {
  if (strlen(trim($sql))>0) {
       mysql_query(trim($sql));
   }
}
```

Comment: this is horribly inefficient if you have say 100 updates to run. it will loop through each and do 100 queries