# Build 2 new tables at once with php

Tags: php, mysql

Im attempting to construct to new mysql tables at once:

```
 public function connect() {
    mysql_connect($this->host,$this->username,$this->password) or die("Could not connect. " . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($this->table) or die("Could not select database. " . mysql_error());
    return $this->buildDB();
  }
    private function buildDB() {
        $sql = <<<MySQL_QUERY
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS projects (
    title       VARCHAR(300),
    projectid   VARCHAR(100)
    )
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS owners (
    projectid   VARCHAR(100),
    owners      VARCHAR(150)
    )
    MySQL_QUERY;

        return mysql_query($sql);
      }
```

This maybe sort of a novice question, but I am having trouble seeing why this wont work - any ideas?

---

**EDIT:** Updated to incorporate @mellamokb idea about splitting up the queries

```
  private function buildDB() {
    $sql = <<<MySQL_QUERY
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS projects (
title       VARCHAR(300),
tags        VARCHAR(390),
description TEXT,
created     VARCHAR(100),
projectimg  VARCHAR(150),
savethumb   VARCHAR(150),
owners      VARCHAR(150),
projectid   VARCHAR(100),
projecturl  VARCHAR(150)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS owners (
projectid   VARCHAR(100),
owners      VARCHAR(150)
)

MySQL_QUERY;

   $arr = split(";", $sql);
   foreach($arr as &$value) {
    return mysql_query($value);
   }
```

So, I updated the original question using split and then a foreach statement to iterate through each 'CREATE TABLE'. Unfortunately only the first table (projects) gets created. Any ideas what could be going on

Comment: Don't update your question to incorporate answers.  Mark the answer as correct if it worked or comment on why it didn't work.  If you have a problem with the new code, start a new question.  This makes the answers no longer relevant to your question.

Comment: It only half-worked. Only the first table gets created. Sorry for editing the original, I just wasn't sure where to show the work.

Comment: A good way to show new information is by adding a `**EDIT**` or `**UPDATE**` section to the bottom of your question and show the changes and new problems so the original is preserved and relevant.  If it gets too complicated, the best thing to do at this point is start a new question with the new problem addressed.  If you do start a new question, you can always link to this one to provide some context.

Comment: You need to move the `return` statement to outside the bottom of the loop, otherwise it returns to the caller of the function immediately after the first query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`mysql_query`](http://php.net/mysql_query) cannot run multiple statements in a single call according to the docs: (emphasis mine)

> **mysql_query()** sends a unique query (**multiple queries are not
>   supported**) to the currently active database on the server that's
>   associated with the specified link_identifier.

You either need to split up the statements into separate calls to `mysql_query`, or make use of the `mysqli` library and [`mysqli_multi_query`](http://php.net/mysqli_multi_query) instead.

If you do go the splitting queries route with `mysql_query`, one easy way to do this is to terminate your statements with `;` as normal in your single script, and then run a PHP command to split around the `;` (like [`split`](http://php.net/split) or [`explode`](http://php.net/explode)).  Then loop through each of the output strings and execute them one at a time.

**EDIT:** Regarding your update: you need to move the `return` statement to outside the bottom of the loop, otherwise it returns to the caller of the function immediately after the first query.

---

Related SO questions (Remarkable what you can [find with Google](http://www.google.com/search?gcx=w&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=php%20mysql_query%20multiple%20queries%20site%3astackoverflow.com#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&source=hp&q=php+mysql_query+multiple+queries+site:stackoverflow.com&pbx=1&oq=php+mysql_query+multiple+queries+site:stackoverflow.com&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=s&gs_upl=0l0l0l11696l0l0l0l0l0l0l0l0ll0l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=365e5209816080a2&biw=1280&bih=963) if you try, isn't it):

- [How to execute two mysql queries as one in PHP/MYSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802437/how-to-execute-two-mysql-queries-as-one-in-php-mysql)
- [PHP MySQL Multi-statement works on my webpage but not on XAMPP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7603571/php-mysql-multi-statement-works-on-my-webpage-but-not-on-xampp)
- [How do you do multiple SQL statments in one mysql_query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821184/how-do-you-do-multiple-sql-statments-in-one-mysql-query)
- [Run multiple MySQL queries from PHP | Why is this not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6573928/run-multiple-mysql-queries-from-php-why-is-this-not-working)
- [How can I put two queries in one mysql_query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988921/how-can-i-put-two-queries-in-one-mysql-query)
- [mysqli multiple queries - set variable produces boolean error/how to skip this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227022/mysqli-multiple-queries-set-variable-produces-boolean-error-how-to-skip-this)
- [Execute multiple sql delete query in mysql for php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164906/execute-multiple-sql-delete-query-in-mysql-for-php)
- [Cannot execute two mysql queries at once in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323372/cannot-execute-two-mysql-queries-at-once-in-php)
- [mysql query works when ran in phpmyadmin, but returns an error when ran in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736296/mysql-query-works-when-ran-in-phpmyadmin-but-returns-an-error-when-ran-in-php)
- [Returns false when running this query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7095480/returns-false-when-running-this-query)
- [mysql muliple queries in one statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642336/mysql-muliple-queries-in-one-statement)
- ahh.. so many.. SO MANY!!

Comment: So, I updated the original question using split and then a foreach statement to iterate through each 'CREATE TABLE'. Unfortunately only the first table (projects) gets created. Any ideas what could be going on?

Comment: See my comment on the question.  Don't incorporate answers to your question because it makes the answers irrelevant and confuses the question.  Put the question back to normal or add the updated code as an **UPDATE** section to your question.  We can continue this conversion via comments, or start a new question if it gets too complicated.

Comment: Can you dump the queries that are getting executed, i.e. `var_dump($value)`, and make sure they look ok.  Also, make sure any error messages are getting reported with `error_reporting(1)` and check the contents of `mysql_error()` after every query.

Comment: Actually it looks like the problem is you are saying `return`, so after the first iteration it will immediately return the value back to the caller...

Answer (score 1):

That is 2 queries you're running there, and to my knowledge only MySQLi supports multi queries. You should check out http://php.net/mysqli